# ADA Chat with ReactJS & NextJS - problem with initialisation when go to other screen

Tags: reactjs

We are using [ADA chatbot](https://www.ada.cx/) with ReactJS and NextJS, but we are facing problems when we go to another page, and the chat closes. Let's say we have 3 pages A,B,C and only on 2 of them we want to have with a chat bubble.
So what I have done is include simple Chat start/stop logic (note: dynamic next import because of client-side rendering).

debug implementation of Chat

```
import { FC, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import adaEmbed from '@ada-support/embed2';
/**
 * warn: in Next.js this must be loaded dynamically only on client side  - how to:
 *
 * import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

 * const Chat = () => {
 *     const Chat = dynamic(() => import('components/Chat'), {
 *         ssr: false,
 *         loading: () => <div>loading</>,
 *     });
 *     return <Chat />;
 * };
 */
const Chat: FC<{ caller: string }> = ({ caller }) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('mounting:', caller);
        adaEmbed
            .start({
                handle: 'HANDLE',
            })
            .then(() => {
                console.log('started:', caller);
            })
        return () => {
            console.log('unmounting:', caller);
            adaEmbed
                .stop()
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('stopped', caller);
                })
        };
    }, [caller]);
    return null;
};

export default Chat;
```

Now what's happening when going from A -> B is this:

```
mounting A
started A
unmounting A
mounting B
started B
stopped A
```

So the starting function from B is quicker than stopping from A.
We need to stop it somewhere as we don't want to run it on page C.

Have you anybody implemented ADA chat with such a setup? Any tips&tricks or different approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting the `useEffect` return function this way:

```
    return async () => {
                console.log('unmounting:', caller);
                await adaEmbed
                    .stop();
                console.log(‘stopped’, caller);
            };
```

Comment: Let me know how it went:)

Comment: I was sooo blind, that was it...many many thanks ;)